# How to replace template in one file with content of another file?

Tags: ant

I have a file username.txt with one word in it.

I have another file with template in it:

```
<root>
   <user name="${username}">
</root>
```

I need during **ant build** change template ${username} with content of file username.txt.
How to do it?
What **ant task** should I use for this purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can make your first file be a [properties file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.properties) instead of containing just the one word e.g.

```
username=superuser
```

Then you can load it using the [property](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/property.html) task. e.g.

```
<property file="username.properties" />
```

**Update**

If the file format needs to remain as in the question then take a look at the [LoadFile](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/loadfile.html) task. It can be used to load the contents of a file into a property. e.g.

```
<loadfile property="username" srcFile="username.txt" />
```

Comment: @Vladimir I have updated the answer with another suggestion to use the `LoadFile` task.